# The Mersenne number $2^{83}-1$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is a solved example on my textbook (in Portuguese) showing that the Mersenne number $2^{83}-1$ is not prime.He says:

We have

$2^{8}=256\equiv 89\mod 167$

$2^{16}\equiv 72 \mod 167$

$2^{32}\equiv 7 \mod 167$

$2^{64}\equiv 49\mod 167$

How did he found out the number $167$?

Comment: Just looking at a pattern here, but $167 = 83*2 + 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a theorem on Mersenne numbers that says "$2p+1$ is prime implies $M_p$ is composite."  Here is the reference on [the prime pages](http://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/); if $p$ is a prime such that $p\equiv 3\pmod 4,$ then

$$2p+1\text{ is prime }\iff 2p+1\mid M_p$$

Comment: I don't know this fact, but a prime $p$ s.t. $2 p + 1$ is also prime is called a *Sophie Germain prime*. Euler proved that if additionally $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, then $2p + 1$ divides the Mersenne prime $M_p := 2^p - 1$.

Comment: And since $83\equiv 3\pmod 4$ we are done. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Factors of a non-prime Mersenne number $M_p$ are of the form $2kp+1$, see  http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/MerDiv.html. And $167$ is just the first member of this class with $k=1\;$ for your $p=83$.

Comment: I love how we both used the prime pages as a reference:-)